# Unit Testing with GHUnit

Tags: iphone, unit-testing, gh-unit

I am new to iPhone Development. I have integrated the framework GHUnitIOS to Test my application. but I haven't found documentation about how to implement Unit testing (it's my first time in Unit Testing).

Can someone can help me to begin with GHUnit, documentations, examples, explanations?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you configure a new target to run tests with GHUnit:

- Download the [GHUnitIOS framework](http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit/downloads). Note the name, don't download the one for OS X.
- Add a new target to your project.
- Add the following frameworks: 
  `GHUnitIOS.framework`,
  `CoreGraphics.framework`,
  `Foundation.framework`,
  `UIKit.framework`,
  `CoreLocation.framework`
- In *Build Settings > Other Linker
  Flags* add `-ObjC` and `-all_load`
- Edit the `...-Info.plist` for your target with a text editor and comment the following:

> ```
> <!--
> <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
> <string>MainWindow</string>
> -->
> ```

- Add the `GHUnitIOSTestMain.m` file into your project.
- In the build settings of your new target, remove the file `main.m`.
- In the .pch file for your new target add `#import <GHUnitIOS/GHUnit.h>`

Now add a test:

```
// this import is already in the pch
// #import <GHUnitIOS/GHUnit.h>

@interface MyTest : GHTestCase { }
@end


@implementation MyTest

- (void)testFoo {
    // assert that foo is not nil
    GHAssertNotNULL(foo, @"foo was nil");
}

@end
```

Your test methods should start with `test`. There are other methods you can add like `setUp`, `tearDown`, `setUpClass`, `tearDownClass`, and a number of `GHAssertxxx` assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about GHUnit, but PragPub had a nice article about TDD on the iPhone using the Google Toolbox - see http://www.pragprog.com/magazines/2010-07/tdd-on-iphone-diy